# No results and no log information in Apache JMeter

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

I have set up a class extending `AbstractJavaSamplerClient`containing a `setupTest`, `runTest` and `getDefaultParameters` method, all written accordingly to the jMeter's templates and online examples.

Have added a Logger, tried setting it up normally (`LoggingManager.getLoggerForClass();`) and using super as well (`super.getLogger();`) and added multiple `Logger.info` and `Logger.error`

I'm using a `Java request` and giving a Jar containing my classes have completed the `user.properties` with the classpath. The right class is selected when running the tests.

When I run my tests, no custom logs appear. No error either. And I'm getting this:

```
2016/02/03 13:34:42 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2016/02/03 13:34:42 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2016/02/03 13:34:42 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2016/02/03 13:34:42 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Group Test
2016/02/03 13:34:42 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Group Test. 
2016/02/03 13:34:42 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will start next loop on error 
2016/02/03 13:34:42 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2016/02/03 13:34:42 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2016/02/03 13:34:42 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2016/02/03 13:34:42 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Group Test 1-1 
2016/02/03 13:34:42 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Group Test 1-1 
2016/02/03 13:34:42 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Group Test 1-1 
2016/02/03 13:34:42 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2016/02/03 13:34:42 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

I've checked the user.properties and the logs are written to `jmeter.log`
I feel like my class is not even tested since the logs are not displaying anything beside "Starting/Done/Finshed Thread".

When I add a result tree or any other result thread, it stays empty.

What could be set up wrong here?

EDIT:
Didn't use the right JAVa request (Configurations>Default Java Request != Single Java Request). From that point I saw I had an error with my Jonas thus not connecting and explaining the non existent results.

Comment: Try to put your jar in `lib/ext` folder under jmeter (so that jmeter find it for sure), and also change log to DEBUG level to see if anything comes up at all.

Answer (score 0):

As per example given in [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) article:

1. Necessary imports:

   ```
   import org.apache.jorphan.logging.LoggingManager;
   import org.apache.log.Logger;
   ```
2. Initialization:

   ```
   private static final Logger log = LoggingManager.getLoggerForClass();
   ```
3. Usage:

   ```
   log.info("your log message");
   log.error("your error message", exception);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for answering, might help some people with similar problems. But didn't help mine :/

Comment: Can you update the question with your class listing? I'm not telepathic enough to tell what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I have quite a lot of classes with all the dependancies. the jar is pretty much only containing 1 class which extends from the AbstractJavaSamplerClient. The fact I get no custom logs is worrying so thought we could go from there.